# Updating row that contains the button

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the form below:

[image: Button Selection Image]

When I select the button to change the status field to Rejected it changes the one that was clicked on before not the row that the button is on.

Is there a way of forcing focus on that record with the selected button before running the code?

Here is the code behind the button:

```vb
DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject
AID = Me.Auto_ID
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Set Mydb = CurrentDb
strSQL = "UPDATE Dev_Proc_ResinToolSpec SET Dev_Proc_ResinToolSpec.Approval = -1 WHERE ResinSpec_AID = " & AID & ";"
Mydb.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges
Me.Recalc 
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

I tried changing the `GoToRecord` to use `acPrevious` but it threw up this error

> You can't go to the specified record

Comment: I can do this by having an embedded macro which has a GoToControl with the control name =[Screen].[PreviousControl].[Name] but when I try and put this into code it will not work.

Comment: Which code? There is no code in your question.  If we don't see the code we cannot tell whats wrong in the code.

Comment: Why don't you use Access conversion tool to convert macro to VBA and see what the result is. Maybe it will show `DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acPrevious`. However, it should not be necessary to move to previous. Post your attempted VBA code.

Comment: Here is my code:  I tried with acPrevious and it came up with an error  "You can't go to the specified record" so I removed it and every time I press the button it selected the next one down starting from the top.                                                                                 DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject
AID = Me.Auto_ID
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Set Mydb = CurrentDb
strSQL = "UPDATE Dev_Proc_ResinToolSpec SET Dev_Proc_ResinToolSpec.Approval = -1 WHERE ResinSpec_AID = " & AID & ";"
Mydb.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges
Me.Recalc
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Comment: I can't put a screen show of the code on here for some reason or of the macro which has the "Convert Macros to Visual Basic" button greyed out.

Comment: @AaronButler Please [edit] your original question and add the code there. In a comment it is pretty much un-readable.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the help but I have now resolved the issue in a round about way.  I created a text field with the word "Reject" in it and one with the word "Approve".  This then selected the row when pressed and ran the rest of the code for that row.  Also conditional formatted it so it disables them when clicked so it can't be clicked twice.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.